# Match Text in a group regardless if their place are changed or not RegEx

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, nsregularexpression

I have the following log message:

```
request="POST /api/settings/update HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 601\r\nsec-ch-ua: %22 Not A;Brand%22;v=%2299%22, %22Chromium%22;v=%22101%22, %22Google Chrome%22;v=%22101%22\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nLang: ar\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: %22Windows%22\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nOrigin: https://example.com\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: same-origin\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: cors\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: empty\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en,ar;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8\r\nCookie: .AspNetCore.Culture=c%3dh-AA%7fgujt%3Dar-AA; BPBBBBBBB=d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5; dm2=!v87cvbt78ffdv76tv87ht87vtsdb879bt879ftb7s6dbt87asdtf786astd7b6as76dftba87fa76sdfbt876asdtbf76sndtb7asdf76t7d6ft76dtbf/OUM=; .AspNetCore.Cookies=sdfgehth87s6dfh876sdfh765dfh675sfdsdf7g5fsrgerh76g-fy00-thrtPlNFc546v54eryrthrtjrtujrtuhv45634v5vkhrB-tyhtr6WRvdyhrth-_dfgtrhCFuQ05QmPch2trP-rtfoNhUrpl8C8xu-tdyhthrthyhth42i40S-hgjgsghjb-ghu56h_a9; BP40sdf215=408a4314117\r\nX-Forwarded-For: 5.65.57.55\r\n\r\n{%22confirmMessage%22:%22Thanks for your feedback%22}"
```

And I have the following Regex:

```
([^r]*(?:r(?!equest=")[^r]*)*request="(?<objectname>([^H]*(?:H(?!ost:)[^H]*)*Host:(?<dname>.*?)\\r\\n)?([^U]*(?:U(?!ser-Agent:)[^U]*)*User-Agent:(?<useragent>.*?)\\r\\n)?([^R]*(?:R(?!eferer:)[^R]*)*Referer:(?<object>[^\\])\\)?([^M]*(?:M(?!essage%22:%22)[^M]*)*Message%22:%22(?<subject>.*?)%22)??[^"]*)")?
```

The above is working fine, but sometimes the message fields are movable as the following:

```
request="POST /api/settings/update HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 601\r\nsec-ch-ua: %22 Not A;Brand%22;v=%2299%22, %22Chromium%22;v=%22101%22, %22Google Chrome%22;v=%22101%22\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nLang: ar\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: %22Windows%22\r\nHost: example.com\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nOrigin: https://example.com\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: same-origin\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: cors\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: empty\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en,ar;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8\r\n"
```

As shown in above message the "User-Agent" came first and then "Host" and in the first message the Host was before User Agent.

Is there a way to match them regardless if their place are changed or not?

Regex Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/Iu7Db8/1

Thanks

Comment: What regex engine/programming tool are you using? Do you have 'look behind' feature?

Comment: @Poul Bak
I'm using PCRE2 PHP, same in this demo: https://regex101.com/r/Iu7Db8/1 , and I tried look behind in the mentioned demo but it wasn't work

Answer (score 0):

The 'trick' here is to use ***look ahead***. The look ahead starts from the beginning of the text every time.

I give you an example here with some of the header names. You can expand it with the names you want following this pattern.

Note that the 'test' name won't match so that group will be undefined:

```
/^(?=.*?request="(?<request>.*?(?=\\r\\n))|)(?=.*?Accept:(?<accept>.*?(?=\\r\\n))|)(?=.*?test:(?<test>.*?(?=\\r\\n))|)(?=.*?Connection:(?<connection>.*?(?=\\r\\n))|)/gm
```

**Explanation:**

`^` - start from the beginning

`(?=` - look ahead for

`.*?request="` - any characters zero or more times followed by '`request="`'

`(?<request>` - group named '`request`'

`.*?` - any characters zero or more times

`(?=\\r\\n)` - look ahead for '`\r\n`'

`)` - end group '`request`'

`|` - OR empty

`)` - end look ahead

You can repeat this pattern with different group names as often as you need.

Now the regex don't care about the order.

Here's the link: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KKjwrl/1)